# $(this) selector working awry

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using inview.js and knobs.js plugins to create a animated knob chart.
I'm using the following code to animate a knob:

```
jQuery('.knobchart').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
if (visible == true) {
    jQuery(this).knob();
    jQuery({
        value: 0
    }).animate({
        value: jQuery(this).attr("rel")
    }, {
        duration: 5000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function () {
            jQuery(this).val(Math.ceil(this.value)).trigger('change');
        }
    })


} else {

$(this).val(0);

}
});
```

The markup for a knob looks like this :

```
<input data-readonly="true" class="knobchart" rel="999" value="0">
```

The problem is that specifying

```
jQuery(this)
```

selector in step function for the animation does nothing.
I tried changing it to

```
'.knobchart'
```

but then all the knobs get animated to same value.

**EDIT: RESOLVED** @Gaby 's method works brilliantly...

Comment: So, use your browser's debugging tools and find out what `this` is.

Comment: Why use alias 'jQuery' when you seem to use '$' too?

Comment: changing to '$' does nothing..

Comment: How do I find out what 'this' is

Comment: console.log($(this));

Comment: [Object, jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", size: function…]
0: Object
value: 9
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Object[0]

Comment: Console returns this ^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: try `console.log(this)` don't wrap it with jQuery

Comment: If you didn't get the answer then you shouldn't mark a post as answer. This let other users assume that you got the answer and they move to next post.

Comment: @TecHunter should i do this with Arun 's solution cos it works partially?

Comment: @ArunPJohny method works but still not rounding off.. Can sm1 help?

Comment: @Sid post from Gaby works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/2h8mF/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store `this` to a variable when you know where it points, and use that variable instead of `this`..

```
jQuery('.knobchart').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
    var self = this; // <-- added this line, and using self from now on in this method
    if (visible == true) {
        jQuery(self).knob();
        jQuery({
            value: 0
        }).animate({
            value: jQuery(self).attr("rel")
        }, {
            duration: 5000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function () {
                jQuery(self).val(Math.ceil(this.value)).trigger('change');
            }
        });

    } else {
        $(self).val(0);
    }
});
```

This is needed because you do not animate an element but an object.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/2h8mF/1/

Comment: @user, did you replace all `this` with `self` ?

Comment: here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/2h8mF/1 (*i commented out the .knob() as i do not have that plugin*). Also made a correction, inside the `val(..)` i had in error replace `this.value` which was correct..

Comment: Try it with more than 1 `<input></input>`

Comment: @sid, i did what about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Why arent you using `$` but `jQuery`? 
You could try to do this within an each loop, which might not be too perfomant:

```
$('.knobchart').each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    el.bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
        if (visible == true) {
            el.knob();
            $({
                value: 0
            }).animate({
                value: el.attr("rel")
            }, {
                duration: 5000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function () {
                    el.val(Math.ceil(this.value)).trigger('change');
                }
            })


        } else {

            el.val(0);

        }
    });
});
```

One question though: what shall the lines

```
jQuery({
        value: 0
    }).animate({
        value: jQuery(this).attr("rel")
    }, {
        duration: 5000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function () {
            jQuery(this).val(Math.ceil(this.value)).trigger('change');
        }
    })
```

do? Looks wrong to me

Comment: well i get that, but the syntax is looking falsy to me. Are you sure those dont throw an error? Did the .each() function work?

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems which I found.

1. `jQuery({value: 0}).animate(...)` is not a valid statement, you need to animate the current element that is `this`
2. Usage of `this` inside the `step` handler, you need to use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to pass a custom context to the callback method

Code

```
jQuery('.knobchart').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
    if (visible == true) {
        jQuery(this).knob();
        jQuery(this).animate({
            value: jQuery(this).attr("rel")
        }, {
            duration: 5000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: $.proxy(function () {
                jQuery(this).val(Math.ceil(this.value)).trigger('change');
            },this)
        })
    } else {
        $(this).val(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: can somebody tell me y its not rounding off?

Comment: describe your solution a bit instead of just posting code please

Comment: @arun would u describe ur method?